# Can I see spartacus storefront in smartedit preview mode of local environment?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, smartedit

I built a local development environment with CX 2005 & spartacus for study purpose.

Spartacus storefront works like a charm.
Url is http://localhost:4200

But I can't see spartacus storefront in local smartedit's preview mode.
(Url is https://localhost:9002/smartedit. Smartdit > Spartacus Electronics Site > Online > Home)

So I realized the spartacus storefront's url in iframe src is start with https not http.

1. Could I change this iframe src to http or Can I launch my spartacus server to https intead of http?

I refered to [Using Angular CLI to serve over https locally](https://medium.com/@richardr39/using-angular-cli-to-serve-over-https-locally-70dab07417c8) and launched spartacus storefront with https, but stil can't see spartacus storefront through smartedit.

2. Or we don't need to see spartacus storefont in smartedit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spartacus site can be displayed in SmartEdit. Follow the procedure here: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/

> Could I change this iframe src to http or Can I launch my spartacus
> server to https intead of http?

Yes, it's recommended to use HTTPS.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know I need an additional setup for smartedit. Really thanks!

Comment: @geffcgabg Thanks to your help, Finally I succeeded. Could you check one more question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64746691/my-smartedit-set-up-for-spartacus-is-normal

Comment: @fat-takumi Good to know it worked for you. Feel free to accept the answer. :)