# My smartedit status for spartacus is normal?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, smartedit

[Can I see spartacus storefront in smartedit preview mode of local environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745019/can-i-see-spartacus-storefront-in-smartedit-preview-mode-of-local-environment) is my previous question about smartedit(CX 2005.0) & spartacus.

Thanks to @geffchang, Finally I could see spartacus storefront in smartedit.

But When I selected any pages in smartedit, these error messages appeared as below.

> SmartEdit is having difficulty loading the page. The page is either
> not compatible with SmartEdit or connection to it has been lost. Wait
> for the page to load or disable editing by going to Preview mode.

After I waited for a moment in no action, I can see additional error message as below.

> No composed type exists

So I clicked the preview link in first error message then browser moved to preview mode.

I move to mouse to "I icon" in left top, I can see alert message as below.

> You cannot change modes. The page is either not compatible with
> SmartEdit or connection to it has been lost. Refresh the page or go to
> another page.

This status of smartedit is all right? Are there any additional set up?
(Please pardon  me for this question might be not a part of spartacus but CX. sorry)

I edit this question.

I just added personalization config to app.module.ts then smartedit's all error messages disappeared.

Furthermore  I could see preview only before, now I can see Basic Edit, Advanced Edit, Personalization.

Does the smartedit take some time to ready for working?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to open HAC first? After that, open the page in SmartEdit again.

Comment: Yes. I can connect hac & backoffice. They look good condition. But I wonder smartedit when I chose spaCatalog is normal.

Comment: @fat-takumi What do you mean by "when I chose spaCatalog is normal."? Can you update your question with screenshots? Show the SmartEdit and the errors. Also, check if there are errors in browser console.

Comment: I just left server alone for a couple of hours so all errors disappeared. I wonder why the error occured at first.

Comment: @fat-takumi Ah, maybe it was an issue with the SSL certificate. So, at first, open the HAC first to load the SSL certificate and the site. After that Storefront and SmartEdit should be fine.